# Breaking public key pinning

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

I was reading through the IETF's Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-key-pinning-12). The acknowledgements section has the following:

```
Thanks to Trevor Perrin for suggesting a mechanism to
affirmatively break Pins
```

Unfortunately, the link is broken in informative references.

Does anyone know anything about the break?

(Moderators: I had to tag this question with something to post it, and PKI was selected (but I realize its not a good choice). The questions should have been tagged similar to 'public-key', 'pin', 'pinning', 'pinset', 'ietf', 'rfc' or a few others. But none of the tags are available).

Comment: A quick Googling came up with this: https://www.mail-archive.com/websec@ietf.org/msg00359.html Assuming that you also did a search, is that discussion not what you were looking for?

Comment: The reason why the link in the IETF draft no longer works appears to be because it has been supplanted by TACK?

Comment: @schroeder - Oh, my bad. I thought Perrin managed to attack and break pinning. It did not register with me that "break" was being used in a "disassociate" or "stop pinning" sense.